# Proper coffeescript syntax for nested function

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

How would one write this with the correct coffeescript syntax?

```
$("select#test").bind({
  "focus": function(ev, obj) {
    # Do something when the focus event is triggered
  }
});
```

My attempt is not correct:

```
$("select#test").bind 
  "focus": (ev, obj) -> 
    # Do something when focus event is triggered
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('select#test').bind 'focus': (ev, obj) ->
  # Do something when the focus event is triggered
  return
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is totally fine. Except for the fact that `//` isn't how you do comments, and that's what's crashing it, haha. `# is for comments`